# Get tags names from json file as a variable in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using C# MVC
I am importing a Json file from a location to an Rest API. In order to display the data. the program needs to know the name of the tags.

I would like to know if there is a way to get the tags from the files in an array of strings and declare them via program instead of manually inputting them.

```
Current C# Code
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SomeID { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

Current Json File:
[{"Id":212,"SomeID":71,"Number":0,"Name":"Mr Jones Mones","Address":"21, street, city"}
```

So as mentioned this code words fine. But, as I am importing data, the tags may contain different information and I would like to have the public declaration in a way that I can import any file to the API and be able to edit and export it.

Thank you

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the problem, what are tags? Properties of the JSON objects?  So it's JSON that can be of any form?

Comment: Try using ExpandoObject to build up an object to work with on the fly at runtime.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you are trying to do, but if you want to be able to parse and manipulate arbitrary JSON, you will probably want to use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JTokens, JObjects, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you use JSON.net you can parse out json into a `JObject` then iterate over it's properties like so, however each property value can be any type of object so you'd need to write something to either recursively listed out nested objects or check if values are strings and only take them if they are etc.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse("{ \"test\": \"test\", \"test1\": \"test1\", \"test2\": \"test2\" }");

foreach (var prop in obj.Properties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [JsonConvert](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) like this:

```
Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonString);
```

Read the docs for JsonConvert for more info.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that was asked.